# fwrite and fread with malloced nested struct does not have expected behaviour

Tags: c, struct, malloc, fwrite, fread

I have an array of nested structs pointers allocated with `malloc`. I want print the array in a binary file and then, load it into this struct again crushing existing records. This is my structs array:

```
struct viaje {
    char *identificador;
    char *ciudadDestino;
    char *hotel;
    int numeroNoches;
    char *tipoTransporte;
    float precioAlojamiento;
    float precioDesplazamiento;
};

struct cliente {
    char *dni;
    char *nombre;
    char *apellidos;
    char *direccion;
    int totalViajes;
    struct viaje *viajes;
} *clientes;
```

I am trying to print it inside a binary file like:

```
for (i = 0; i < MAX_TAM_CLIENTES; i++) {
    fwrite(&clientes[i], sizeof(struct cliente)-(sizeof(struct viaje)*MAX_TAM_VIAJES_CLIENTE), 1, fp_guardarCargarEstado);

    for (j = 0; j < clientes[i].totalViajes; j++) {
        fwrite(&clientes[i].viajes[j], sizeof(struct viaje), 1, fp_guardarCargarEstado);
    }
}
```

Where:

`MAX_TAM_CLIENTES` is a define. Is the max size of array `clientes`,
`MAX_TAM_VIAJES_CLIENTE` is a define. Is the max size of array `viajes` inside one clientes

Also, I try to load this binary data like:

```
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_TAM_CLIENTES; i++) {
        clientes = (struct cliente *)realloc(clientes, (totalClientes+1)*sizeof(struct cliente));
        clientes[totalClientes].dni = (char *)malloc((MAX_TAM_DNI+1)*sizeof(char));
        clientes[totalClientes].nombre = (char *)malloc((MAX_TAM_NOMBRE+1)*sizeof(char));
        clientes[totalClientes].apellidos = (char *)malloc((MAX_TAM_APELLIDOS+1)*sizeof(char));
        clientes[totalClientes].direccion = (char *)malloc((MAX_TAM_DIRECCION+1)*sizeof(char));

        fread(&clientes[i], sizeof(struct cliente)-(sizeof(struct viaje)*MAX_TAM_VIAJES_CLIENTE), 1, fp_guardarCargarEstado);

        for (j = 0; j < clientes[i].totalViajes; j++) {
            clientes[i].viajes = (struct viaje *)realloc(clientes[i].viajes, (j+1)*sizeof(struct viaje));
            clientes[i].viajes[j].identificador = (char *)malloc((MAX_TAM_IDENTIFICADOR+1)*sizeof(char));
            clientes[i].viajes[j].ciudadDestino = (char *)malloc((MAX_TAM_CIUDAD_DESTINO+1)*sizeof(char));
            clientes[i].viajes[j].hotel = (char *)malloc((MAX_TAM_HOTEL+1)*sizeof(char));
            clientes[i].viajes[j].tipoTransporte = (char *)malloc((MAX_TAM_TIPO_TRANSPORTE+1)*sizeof(char));

            fread(&clientes[i].viajes[j], sizeof(struct viaje), 1, fp_guardarCargarEstado);
        }
    }
```

Where:

`MAX_TAM_*` are defines. They are the maximum size of each field.

But I do not know if `fwrite` is saving good the data due to when I try load it, program crash and is not loading data.

I do not know how could be wrong there. Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: "Anidated" is not an English word I know (but I'm not a native speaker). One translation from Spanish seems to be "nested". Is that what you mean? Sorry for not helping with the actual question.

Comment: Yes, right. I wanna say nested, title of the question is already modified. Thank you so much. And no problem, don't be worried about question :)

Comment: Tip: Better to use fixed width types like `int32_t` than `int` to save an _integer_.

Comment: Ok, I will take it in care, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot save the full contents of these structures with `fwrite` and read them back with `fread`, because they contain pointers to strings, not the actual characters.

There are 2 ways to achieve your goals:

- save the contents as text in a standard format such as XML or simply CSV where each entry is written on a single line with the different fields are separated by `,`.
- change the structures to store the strings as arrays of `char` instead of pointers to allocated storage. `If you open the files as binary, you should be able to write the structures and read them back with`fread`.

Be aware however that the latter approach is much less flexible than the textual approach:

- if you change the structure, you can no longer read previously saved contents with the new version of the program.
- the binary format is potentially not portable to another architecture, such as a smartphone, because the representation of `int` may be different.
- the member `struct viaje *viajes;` must also be replaced with an actual structure without any pointers.

Comment: Oh, ok, thank you so much! I tought that it could be possile. I will take your advice in care.